# Jquery add ellipse (...) and truncate text based on height not width

Tags: javascript, jquery, truncate

I have found many ways to measure width and to truncate text using jquery, but I can't find one based on height.

I am limited to two lines of text or it will knock my design out of canter.

So does anyone know a method of limiting a paragraph to two lines high, tuncating it and adding an elipse ?

Comment: Here's one way of doing it using pure JS: http://jsfiddle.net/bedex78/3h4zbj3x/. Just do modifications on it to use jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS overflow with a `<div>...</div>` positioned at the bottom?

Comment: You can easily run a short piece of javascript to see if the contents height is more then the set height. If so you display the .. div.